# Mac Os turn off display - change shortcut

Tags: macos

In Mac Os we can use hotkeys for turn off display (control shift eject) or restart, shutdown etc. Now I am use keyboard without eject button and can't use this functionality, is it possible to reassign this actions to another buttons (if possible - without external apps and tools)?

(I searched in keyboard->shortcuts, not helped)

Comment: Does `F12` work as `Eject` key substitute?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it's called in english, but OS X provides "hot corners" which you can customize. Turning off the screen is also possible that way. Might be a suitable alternative to a keyboard shortcut.

Have a look at this link on how it's done:

http://www.macworld.com/article/2042242/what-s-hot-about-os-x-s-hot-corners.html

Comment: I imagine having a hot corner that turned off your monitor would be extremely frustrating!

Comment: Not at all. That's how I lock my working machine all the time when I'm leaving my desk.